# ICS httppost NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, http-post, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am having an issue when trying to access a remote database.  This issue only occurs on ICS or above, but runs perfectly fine on older Android.  I can't figure this one out for the life of me, and have been stuck on it for weeks.  I really need to figure this out so I can then use the solution here in another app of mine that is far more important.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  If more information is needed, just let me know.

Now the app wont even launch, getting the following when launch:

```
11-30 15:42:46.970: W/dalvikvm(10028): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d04210)
11-30 15:42:46.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10028): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-30 15:42:46.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10028): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.defsoftsol.db.check/com.defsoftsol.db.check.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-30 15:42:46.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10028):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
11-30 15:42:46.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10028):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
11-30 15:42:46.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10028):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
11-30 15:42:46.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10028):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
11-30 15:42:46.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10028):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-30 15:42:46.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10028):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-30 15:42:46.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10028):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4428)
11-30 15:42:46.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10028):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-30 15:42:46.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10028):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-30 15:42:46.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10028):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
11-30 15:42:46.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10028):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
11-30 15:42:46.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10028):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-30 15:42:46.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10028): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-30 15:42:46.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10028):    at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1794)
11-30 15:42:46.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10028):    at com.defsoftsol.db.check.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:43)
11-30 15:42:46.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10028):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
11-30 15:42:46.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10028):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
11-30 15:42:46.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10028):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
11-30 15:42:46.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10028):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
11-30 15:42:46.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10028):    ... 11 more
```

UPDATED CODE: (Now the code for entire app)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String deviceID="",dateStamp="",buff="",db_id="",db_device_id="",db_install_date="";       
byte[] data;    
HttpPost httppost;    
StringBuffer buffer;    
HttpResponse response;    
HttpClient httpclient;    
InputStream inputStream;    
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
int ID,activeinstalls;
long diff;
TableLayout tl=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.db_data);

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button refresh = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnrefresh);
    refresh.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new MyAsyncTask(MainActivity.this).execute();

        }
    });
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused") 
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
{ 

    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private Context context;

    public MyAsyncTask(Context context) { 
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    } 

    @Override 
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Loading...", "Data is Loading..."); 
    } 

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        update(); 
        return null; 
    }
}

private final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
private final long ONE_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public void update()
{
    int activeinstalls = 0;
    Date now = new Date();
    dateStamp = formatter.format(now);

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){ 
        @Override 
        public void run(){ 
            UISetup();
        }
    });

    ID = 1;
    try
    {
        do
        {
            try 
            {                    
                httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();                    
                httppost = new HttpPost("http://#.#.#.#/***.php"); //Address cut for server security                    

                nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);                   
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("_id", String.valueOf(ID)));                    
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                response = httpclient.execute(httppost);                    
                inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();                     
                data = new byte[256];                     
                buffer = new StringBuffer();                    
                int len = 0;                    
                while (-1 != (len = inputStream.read(data)) )                    
                {                        
                    buffer.append(new String(data, 0, len));                    
                }
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {                    
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(buffer.charAt(0)=='Y')
            {
                ID++;
                buff = buffer.toString();
                db_id = buff.substring(1, buff.indexOf("."));
                db_device_id = buff.substring(buff.indexOf(".")+1, buff.indexOf(","));
                db_install_date = buff.substring(buff.indexOf(",")+1, buff.length());

                Date before = null;
                try {
                    before = (Date)formatter.parse(db_install_date);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                diff = now.getTime() - before.getTime(); 

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){ 
                    @Override 
                    public void run(){ 
                        UIAdd(diff,db_id,db_device_id,db_install_date);
                    }
                });

            } else { //IF buffer returns N
                //  TODO: Fill in
            }
        } while(buffer.charAt(0)=='Y');

        UIFinish();

    } catch(Exception err) {
        err.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void UISetup()
{
    tl.removeAllViews();
    dbline();
    TableRow titr = new TableRow(this); 
    titr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams( LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
    TextView dbid0 = new TextView(this); 
    TextView dbdevid0 = new TextView(this);
    TextView dbindate0 = new TextView(this);
    dbid0.setText("|   " + "_id");
    dbdevid0.setText("|   " + "device_id");
    dbindate0.setText("|   "+ "install_date"+"    |");

    titr.addView(dbid0); 
    titr.addView(dbdevid0);
    titr.addView(dbindate0);
    tl.addView(titr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    dbline();
}
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void UIAdd(long diffr, String dbidn,String did,String idate)
{
    long days;
    days = diffr / ONE_DAY;
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this); 
    tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams( LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
    TextView dbid = new TextView(this); 
    TextView dbdevid = new TextView(this);
    TextView dbindate = new TextView(this);
    dbid.setText("|   " + dbidn);
    dbdevid.setText("|   " + did);
    dbindate.setText("|   " + idate+"   |");

    if(days <= 7)
    {
        activeinstalls++;
        if(days <= 3) 
        {
            dbid.setTextColor(Color.GREEN); 
            dbdevid.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            dbindate.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        } else {
            dbid.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
            dbdevid.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
            dbindate.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        }

    } else {
        dbid.setTextColor(Color.RED); 
        dbdevid.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        dbindate.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }

    tr.addView(dbid); 
    tr.addView(dbdevid);
    tr.addView(dbindate);
    tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
public void UIFinish()
{
    dbline();

    TextView te = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.totalentries);
    te.setText(String.valueOf(ID-1));
    TextView au = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.activeusers);
    au.setText(String.valueOf(activeinstalls));
}
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void dbline()
{
    TableLayout tl=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.db_data);
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this); 
    tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams( LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
    TextView dbid = new TextView(this); 
    TextView dbdevid = new TextView(this);
    TextView dbindate = new TextView(this);
    dbid.setText("+---------");
    dbdevid.setText("+-------------------------------");
    dbindate.setText("+--------------------+");

    tr.addView(dbid); 
    tr.addView(dbdevid);
    tr.addView(dbindate);
    tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
```

}

Comment: It seems that your inputStream does not return any data. Do you toast a network operation on main thread error?

Comment: Im fairly new to Android dev, care to tell me how? lol Sorry for being a noob.  Also, why would the stream be empty when running on ICS, but not on older Android?

Comment: android >= 3.0 does not allow `NetworkRequest` on main thread! you need to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to call web request

Comment: this subroutine is being called from within asynctask

Comment: I guess it is not! as you are doing `UI operations` in above written code

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem  Please add NPEs and posting stack traces for "I get this error" questions...

Comment: @Simon Sorry I did not get you!

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem Ah, you deleted your comment!  I was just joking with a wish list of things to add to your SO banner.

Comment: Actually your right, do to the fact that I couldnt get it to update the UI thread from asynctask i told it all to run on ui thread as seen in the newly added code at the top.

Comment: You have to put all the network things in the asynch task and use runOnUiThread only when you have to run in the UI thread, like updating views.

Comment: I tried that and it didnt work for me, but i may have flubbed it, ill try again with the updated try catch and see if gets better results

Comment: @Simon NPE is not a strong candidate as it can be due to different reasons but `NetworkOnMainThreadException` is obvious!

Comment: Yes, try to separate your code at least in 2 methods. One which does all the UI things and other which fetches the data. Fetch the data in the thread and when you get it, run the UI-method in runOnUiThread();

Comment: Review question, updated entire thing with new issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get an Exception in the try block, and don't initialize buffer. That's why you get the Null pointer.

You should put everything in the try-catch. Or think better about how to handle it.

And, you also should output the error from the try catch in the console. And show it to us. We can look at it.

Comment: nice one ! As a complement, you should consider adding a return in the catch block if processing is stopped.

Comment: I would put the access to the buffer object also in the try block.

Comment: I would also break this large try block into different methods and yes putting them all inside the try block could be a good idea.

Comment: Also, take the habit to log any exception received in a catch block. It will definitely help to find the bug.

Comment: What would be a better way to handle this?  Basically what this does is queries my remote database on my server, and adds a new line to the screen for each entry it finds.

Comment: At least you should put the operations which depend of the code in try-catch also in the try-catch. And as said, you should output the error you are getting in the try catch to the console, for example: Log.e("error", e.printStackTrace()); So you can copy it here and we can analyze it.

Comment: Ill do so, give me a few as I tried something else and now have to revert to what i had

Comment: Again forgive me for being a total novice, but when I put a try/catch as so:
`} catch (ParseException err) {
    Log.e("error", err.printStackTrace());
}`
the e in Log.e has an error that says: The method e(String, String) in the type Log is not applicable for the arguments (String, void)

You'll have to forgive me, Ive never used the log this way before, never needed to.

Comment: Ah... sorry! Friday evening ;) put `err.printStackTrace();` alone.

Comment: Ixx... I love you, and the rest of you too lol.  I put the marked section of code above into a try catch loop just to get better error message, and instead the app now functions in the emulator.  Will confirm fixed by loading to my phone.

Comment: put entire do / while loop in try catch block and not the line `Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` works and toasts a networkonmainthread exception

Answer (score 0):

try to make the structure some thing like this

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Do network oprations here
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Update UI here
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

Comment: The issue with this is that the UI updates multiple times when the update method is ran.  (Currently 50+ times) Wouldnt doing this only allow for one update UI update?

Comment: yes it would be the problem with your current setup. Why not you make your layout in a xml file. Instead of makeing like `new TextView()` and intilize them in `onCreate`.